# Ham radio as a weapon?

Tags: rfi

So I have a weird situation happening and I'm not sure how to go about this.   I've been getting headaches and weird sensations throughout my body as well my ears are ringing.  Are there directional antennas for ham radio? Our lights flicker quite a bit. I have had drama with my neighbors and am curious if this can be harming my health and well being.

Comment: The only way I know a ham can be weaponized is to bore you to death with the details about their latest near-DX QSO.

Comment: Or I suppose they could ask you to "hold this end of the wire while I tune up".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to dismiss your problem, but I have to close your question because we can't really answer it objectively.  The consensus of us here is that the possibility of ham radio being your problem is extremely remote.  In my opinion you should consult a neurologist.

Comment: Also, hello and welcome!

Comment: With *radio* or with *ham* radio?

Comment: the symptoms you experience are things that most people experience sometimes, but don't pay attention to, until they start suffering from confirmation bias

Answer (score 3):

At the power limits of ham radio and at the frequencies used, the physiological effects you are experiencing are most likely due to something else in your environment other than radio waves in the wavelength range of 300 meters to 10 meters.

There are indeed directional antennas for ham radio, but they are easily recognizable because they are so big that it is almost impossible to hide them. If you can imagine an old-school (analog) rooftop TV antenna that is about 10 feet long and 3 feet wide, a shortwave version of that would be about 20 feet long and 20 feet wide, and it would be on top of a tower at least 40 feet high in order to exhibit directionality.

Ham radio transmissions cannot make your lights flicker.

Comment: Not to mention the inverse-square law.